# VBA split string into substrings from file directory

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

I've searched for this topic a lot but haven't found my exact issue. Also I seemingly can't figure out how to adapt the code samples for my use.

I'm trying to split a "file directory string" into substrings from right to left.

```
"C:\Users\Me\CustomerName\ProductName\2017\"
```

And split this from right to left, to

```
year
productname
customername
```

My attempts at using Split() to get it working, have always split it in the wrong places.

Comment: Update your question with the code you tried so far, as well as examples of the the unwanted behaviour/output ("...split in the wrong places.") Also: are you sure about the `==` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you have tried with `Split`, so this is a good start:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strFolderString As String
    Dim arrFolderString As Variant

    strFolderString = "C:\Users\Me\CustomerName\ProductName\2017\"
    arrFolderString = Split(strFolderString, "\")

    Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 1)
    Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 2)
    Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 3)

End Sub
```

The idea is to use `UBound` as the right to left. I do not start from 0, because your string ends with `\`, thus the 0th position is empty.

Comment: Hi, thanks that works. Your

`Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 1)`

`Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 2)` 

`Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 3)`


output the wrong substring though, they are all shifted one too far to the left. I've changed it to 

`Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 0)
Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 1)
Debug.Print arrFolderString(UBound(arrFolderString) - 2)`

and now it works exactly as wanted. Thanks again!

Edit: Sorry for formatting, I'm new to SO

Comment: @DMS - your string ends with `\\`, that's why I am using it this way. Try the code above.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Apparently my real code's string didn't have the \ in the end. Now working flawlessly though, thanks for your help :)